# Flutter load Image.network() from google cloud platform

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage

I have uploaded some assets to my project in Google Cloud Storage. GCS provides URLs of this type for uploaded files:

`https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-app.appspot.com/items/Peach.jpg`

This URL does *not* work as an argument to `Image.network()` in flutter, probably because it redirects to a long, not really human readable URL if opened in a browser.

Is there a way to use the `gs://` link provided by GCS in flutter? Or do I need to use the `cloud_storage` plugin to download the image within the flutter app and save it as a temporary local file to use it?

Please note that most images live *within* the flutter app, but there is some stuff I'd like to change on the fly without having to re-release through the relevant stores.

Comment: Generally speaking, you use the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage to get an HTTPS download URL, and use that to load the image.

Comment: The long, long HTTPS URL which is redirected to (as above) does indeed work as an arg to `Image.network` - I take it this is the URL returned by the SDK?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The URL you're showing here is not exactly the same as what the SDK would generate.

Comment: The `storage.cloud.google.com/...` URL above, if opened in a web browser, redirects to a much longer `guid-apidata.googleusercontent.com` URL to view the image. This latter URL is probably what is returned by the Firebase SDK `getDownloadURL()` method as it works fine in `Image.network()`.

Comment: It's not the same as what Firebase does.

Comment: Ok - I will experiment tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public bucket and then instead of `https://storage.cloud.google.com` use the public URL `https://storage.googleapis.com/`.

If you need to keep the bucket private you can use the big URL you're redirected to.